# Run Select statement in Stored Procedure based on conditional logic

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I've recently been simplifying many formally manual processes on SQL Server 2008 into stored procedures. I'm attempting to turn the below multi-step process into a stored procedure with conditional logic, but not sure how to accomplish this.

1. Run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vw_GENERIC_VIEW_NAME`
2. Run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_SIMPLE_TABLE_NAME`
3. Compare results and if they are not equal run a `SELECT` statement against `tbl_SIMPLE_TABLE_NAME` to analyze details.

Is there a way to compare the results through some sort of conditional logic and only run the final `SELECT` statement if they are not equal in a stored procedure on SQL Server?

Comment: If your tables are large you may find that [counting using the catalog views is much faster](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way) - e.g. `SELECT [Count] = SUM(Rows) FROM sys.partitions p WHERE p.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tbl_SIMPLE_TABLE_NAME', 'U')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IF` statement with `<>` operator

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vw_GENERIC_VIEW_NAME) <> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_SIMPLE_TABLE_NAME)
BEGIN
Select ... From tbl_SIMPLE_TABLE_NAME
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just compare the counts from the 2 tables in an `IF` statement and conditionally execute code within the block if the valued don't match:

```
IF ( SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM   vw_GENERIC_VIEW_NAME
   ) != ( SELECT    COUNT(*)
          FROM      tbl_SIMPLE_TABLE_NAME
        )
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'NOT EQUAL - run your code in place of this print statement'
    END
```